# How can I resolve these compilation errors related to template context and lookup in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm new to C++ and currently working on a project using MeVisLab. During the build process, I am encountering a compilation error in my C++ project and could use some assistance in resolving it. I'm getting the following errors:

> C:\Program
> Files\MeVisLab3.7.2\Packages\MeVis\Foundation\Sources\MLLinearAlgebra\mlLinearAlgebraTools.h(77,13):
> error C3861: 'MLAbs': identifier not found C:\Program
> Files\MeVisLab3.7.2\Packages\MeVis\Foundation\Sources\MLLinearAlgebra\mlLinearAlgebraTools.h(77,13):
> message : 'MLAbs': function was not declared in the template
> definition context and can be found only via argument-dependent lookup
> in the instantiation context C:\Program
> Files\MeVisLab3.7.2\Packages\MeVis\Foundation\Sources\MLLinearAlgebra\mlMatrix4.h(709):
> message : see reference to function template instantiation 'BASE_TYPE
> ml::MLInverseMatHelper<ml::Tmat4>(const BASE_TYPE &,bool
> *,const double,const char *const ,const BASE_TYPE &,const size_t)' being compiled

I've checked and found that 'MLAbs' and 'MLValueIs0WOM' are declared in 'mlTypeDefs.h' located within C:\Program Files\MeVisLab3.7.2\Packages\MeVis\Foundation\Sources\MLUtilities. However, the errors are occurring in files located in C:\Program Files\MeVisLab3.7.2\Packages\MeVis\Foundation\Sources\MLLinearAlgebra.

I've tried including the necessary directories using `include_directories`, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Could someone please help me understand how to correctly include these definitions or configure my project to resolve these errors?

Additional context:

I'm converting this project from a .pro file to cmake using the [MeVisLab Tool Runner](https://mevislabdownloads.mevis.de/docs/current/MeVisLab/Resources/Documentation/Publish/SDK/CMakeManual/index.html#convertProFileToCMakeScript).

Here's a snippet of my CMakeLists.txt for reference:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
> project(DnlImageLoad)
>
> find_package(MeVisLab COMPONENTS BackgroundTasks DicomTree
> DicomTreeImagePropertyExtension ML Parser Utilities HINTS
> $ENV{MLAB_ROOT} REQUIRED)
> find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Gui Widgets
> REQUIRED)
>
> set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

Other include_directories and target_sources...

> target_link_libraries(DnlImageLoad   PRIVATE
> MeVisLab::BackgroundTasks
> MeVisLab::DicomTree
> MeVisLab::DicomTreeImagePropertyExtension
> MeVisLab::ML
> MeVisLab::Parser
> MeVisLab::Utilities
> Qt5::Core
> Qt5::Gui
> Qt5::Widgets )
>
> include_directories("C:/Program Files/MeVisLab3.7.2/Packages/MeVis/Foundation/Sources/MLUtilities")
> include_directories("C:/Program Files/MeVisLab3.7.2/Packages/MeVis/Foundation/Sources/MLAlgebra")

Additionally, I want to clarify that I'm not adding or removing these headers manually. Instead, the issue is happening in MeVisLab's source code, where one file is using function declared in another but can't find it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Maybe the order of your #include <> statements matter. Maybe you need a `#include <mlTypeDefs.h>` before `#include <mlLinearAlgebraTools.h>` Maybe there is some configuration step missing.

Comment: It is not true that a fix for a particular C++ compilation error is always determined merely by reading the error message. The error message only offers an initial hint what issue is. The actual fix is determined by looking at the failing code, understanding it, and determining why it is ill-formed. C++ is too complicated and sometimes there's nothing wrong with the cited code, but the actual problem occured before, but the suffering C++ compiler struggled for a bit in its quest to make sense of the code, before finally giving up. TLDR: Only you have the failing code, and can figure this out.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at this @drescherjm. I have added some additional information here. Hoping it helps you help me. Thanks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for your insights. I have added some more context in order to clarify the issue better. Please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Which part of the added "context" consists of the actual, failing code?

Comment: So you are saying that you had a working .pro file and now you are trying to convert this to CMake but with the same configuration the CMake fails with this error?

Comment: I don't think the solution would involve adding additional include_directories. You really have to look in and understand why `mlTypeDefs.h` is not being automatically included in your CMake versus QMake.

Comment: @drescherjm that's correct. I used the MeVisLab tool runner for converting from the pro file to cmake. I haven't made any changes to the code for which I'm using cmake. When I try to build the project using the generate CMakeLists.txt, that's when I get the build errors.

Comment: @drescherjm `mlTypeDefs.h` is not being included in my cmake automatically. The errors are happening within the MevisLab package code itself. I added the include_directories with the `mlTypeDefs.h` in my cmake so that the `mlAlgebraTools.h` within MevisLab can find the declarations.

Comment: You may want to ask at the forums for this software: https://forum.mevislab.de